# Virtual Buttons (Vuforia) don't wait for touch

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Having really strange problem. Lots of people can't make VB work at all, but my buttons activate as soon as the target is found, automaticaly! 
I have 4 buttons and 4 URL link on them. When target is found my browser open ALL these links in one moment.

Script is a component of ImageTarget. 
My code:

```
void Start() { 
    VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vbs = GetComponentsInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vbs.Length; ++i) {
        // Register with the virtual buttons TrackableBehaviour
        vbs[i].RegisterEventHandler(this);
    }}

public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb) { 
    switch (vb.VirtualButtonName) {
        case "VBtn1": 
            Application.OpenURL("http://www.shop.mts.ru/smartfony/nokia/smartfon-lumia-830-black.html"); 
            break;
        case "VBtn2": 
            Application.OpenURL("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMwQ9Fxp5_g"); 
            break;
        case "VBtn3": 
            Application.OpenURL("https://vk.com/mts"); 
            break;
        case "VBtn4": 
            Application.OpenURL("https://www.facebook.com/mts?fref=ts"); 
            break;
        }
        }

public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonAbstractBehaviour vb) { 
    return;
}
```

Plz, tell me, what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Please use the unity3d tag, instead of unity (which is not about the game engine).

Comment: Seems thats a target fault. Its OK in test one (stones. for example) and it failed with image target I really need